# Is there a way to filter out closed questions?

Tags: support

It seems that closed questions can still be edited, which is kind of annoying since edits make questions pop up in my view as active. The most egregious example I've come across is [An extension to the real number line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266165/an-extension-to-the-real-number-line). Can closed questions be made uneditable? Or can they be made to not appear as Active? Or is there a way to filter them out of my views? Or is there a status beyond closed, like deleted-so-as-to-never-be-seen-again?

Comment: The question has been deleted.  Maybe we should have engaged in a barrage of downvoting. I like the fact that this community is reluctant to DV, but maybe some bad behavior deserves an exception. And in this case, a DV for every edit might have been instructive. (A question with a score less than -3 does not show up on the active stack.)

Comment: Ah, good to know (about the -3). Yeah, I left a comment asking the poster to stop making edits (I was not the first), and it looks like the poster finally took the hinkt.

Comment: *"Can closed questions be made uneditable? Or can they be made to not appear as Active?"* I think these two ideas implied by the questions are undesirable. The present example aside, questions may be rightfully fighting to be re-opened, and activity on a closed question is important and should not be removed from the *"Active"* list.

Comment: (I want to -1, I understand that downvotes in meta mean disagreement and not bad quality questions. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.)

Comment: @rhermans I've seen up/down votes used that way. Note that if the vote total on a meta question falls to -8 or lower, it is removed from the active stack, which makes it difficult for others participate. So downvoting carries a weak implication that it's a "bad" question. It makes more sense to me to have two answers stating the opposing positions. Or one could have as many answers as there are positions. Then upvotes could give a sense of the community feeling. Of course people might up *and* down vote different positions because they feel entitled to, so there are imperfections.

Comment: I'm not really sure it matters, but jumping back in to this anyway... My question was primarily focused on what options I, individually, had to deal with the issue. E.g., was there a filter option that I wasn't seeing? Or, with enough reputation points, would I be able to cast a vote for Delete? I wasn't really making suggestions for how to re-design how StackExchange works.

Comment: So, while I don't mind having my question here downvoted (unless there are some negative consequences to that that I'm not aware of), I do think downvotes would be inappropriate. I added the "support" tag, which I thought indicated that I was asking for support/help-type answers. And for what it's worth, learning about the -3 threshold was helpful and in line with the kind of answer I expected.

Comment: @lericr the search function has `closed:` among its [options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching). It also has date options so you can maybe use created:7d closed:no in the search box to find all posts in the last 7 days that were not closed